# Recording steganographed audio

Tags: audio, steganography

Using echo hiding or phase coding is it possible to encode a file wav file, play it, and decode the recorded version of the file without losing info? If its not possible with this techniques, are there other other ones that you would recommend to be able to do so?

Comment: a key aspect of problem solving especially when writing software as an aid is to shoot first and ask questions later.. meaning I strongly suggest you take your idea and crank out some code to explore . what you discover may surprise ...  what you speak of essentially is a protocol which is an agreement between sender and receiver on how to formulate the transport of information . this protocol is up to you the explorer .. I suggest you take a long walk and think about the available tools at hand .. start simple namely ignore trying to hide this info xfer and simply send arbitrary data as audio

Comment: a byte of data  is 2 ^ 8 distinct values ( 256 values ) so synthesize a sin curve at frequency X then inspired by Morse Code add on top of this sin wave some disturbance which can be understood by receiver to denote one of those 256 values ... repeat this 256 ways to convey each of these 256 values baked into a single byte of data ... perhaps be OK only achieving less than this 256 count say try to achieve transporting two such values possibly meaning yes or no ... have the sender distort the sin to define a yes and make the receiver side understand a yes do similar for sending a no

Comment: due to `Nyquist Limit`  higher frequencies can transport more information so to denote a yes perhaps combine your underlying sin curve ( carrier signal ) say 300 Hertz with three chirps of a much higher frequency say 7500 Hertz then on receiving side to a FFT call to pluck out this 8500 Hertz traffic and when receiver sees three such spikes you just received a yes ... then for a no do similar at say 9500 Hertz